# Is this a fact about infinite dimensional vector spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces

First, I'll state simply what the claim is that I think might be true:

**Claim 1** If $X$ is an infinite dimensional vector space then for any finite set of vectors $M=\{\vec{V_1}, \vec{V_2},...,\vec{V_n}\}$ there is a vector $\vec{U}$ that is not a linear combination of any of the members of $M$.

And here's why I'm hoping that it is:

I'm trying to show that if $X$ is an infinite dimensional vector space then there is a sequence of infinite subspaces ${U_1,U_2,U_3,...}$ such that for any sequence $\vec{F_1} \in U_1,\vec{F_2} \in U_2,\vec{F_3} \in U_3,...$, the set $\{{\vec{F_1},\vec{F_2},\vec{F_3},...}\}$ does not contain an infinite subspace of $X$.

If claim 1 is true then we should be able to select $U_1,U_2,U_3,...$ so that all members of $U_{n+1}$ are linearly independent from $U_n$, and so a sequence of selections from $U_1,U_2,U_3$ will be linearly independent. But no linearly independent set or subset of a linearly independent set can be a subspace. So we're done.

Comment: Yes, finitely generated vector spaces are finite dimensional.

Answer (score 3):

If there are vectors $v_1,...,v_n \in V$ such that $V = \operatorname{sp} \{ v_1,...,v_n \}$, then, by definition, $V$ is finite dimensional.

Hence an infinite dimensional space cannot have a finite number of vectors with the given property.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that there is a finite set of vectors $M=\{\vec{V_1}, \vec{V_2},...,\vec{V_n}\}$ such that any vector $\vec{U} \in X$ is a linear combination of any of the members of $M$.  Then $X = \text{span}(M)$ and its dimension is at most $n$ (because $M$ contains at most $n$ linear independent vectors).